# Normal u.c.p extension of Schur-multiplier

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm struggeling with the proof of a theorem in [BO08]. The first part before the line is what I think I understood. The part after that I don't understand at all.

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group and $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ the group ring of $\Gamma$. Let $C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)$ be the reduced group $C^\ast$-algebra, i.e. the completion of $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ wrt. the norm $\|x\|=\|\lambda(x)\|$ where λ is the left regular representation of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{B}(\ell^2(\Gamma)$. Let $$L(\Gamma) = C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)'' \subset \mathcal{B}(\ell^2(\Gamma))$$ be the so called group von Neumann algebra. The full group $C^\ast$-algebra is defined as $C^*(\Gamma) = \overline{\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)}^{\|\cdot\|_u}$ with $\| x\|_u = \sup\{ \|\pi(x)\| \; | \; \pi \text{ is a unitary representation of } \Gamma\}$.

For two $C^\ast$-algebras $A$ and $B$ we say that a map $\varphi_A\to B$ is u.c.p if $\varphi$ is unital and $\varphi_n:M_n(A)→M_n(B)$ defined by $\varphi_n([a_{i,j}])=[\varphi(a_{i,j})]$ maps positive matrices to positive matrices for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

$\varphi$ is called normal if it is continuous wrt. ultra-weak topology.

A function $\varphi:\Gamma\to \mathbb{C}$ is called positive definite if for every finite subset $F:=\{s_1, \dots, s_n\}\subseteq \Gamma$ the matrix
$$[\varphi(s_i^{-1}s_j)]_{i,j}\in M_n(\mathbb{C}) $$
is positive semidefinite.

For a function $\varphi:\Gamma\to\mathbb{C}$ set
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
w_\varphi: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma] &\to \mathbb{C}\\
\sum_{t\in\Gamma}\alpha_t t &\mapsto \sum_{t\in\Gamma} \alpha_t \varphi(t)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
m_\varphi: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma] &\to \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\\
\sum_{t\in\Gamma}\alpha_t t &\mapsto \sum_{t\in\Gamma} \alpha_t \varphi(t)t.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The map $m_\varphi$ is also called the Schur-multiplier.

Theorem(2.5.11, [BO08])Let $\varphi:\Gamma\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function with $\varphi(e) =1$. The following conditions are equivalent:

- The functional $w_\varphi$ extends to a positive functional on $C^\ast(\Gamma)$.
- The Schur multiplier $m_\varphi$ extends to a u.c.p. map on the two group $C^\ast$-algebras $C^\ast(\Gamma)$ and $C^\ast_\lambda (\Gamma)$ and to a normal u.c.p map on $L(\Gamma)$.

Proof:Since $w_\varphi$ extends to a functional on $C^\ast(\Gamma)$ it follows that $w_\varphi$ extends to a state on $C^\ast(\Gamma)$, which will also be denoted by $w_\varphi$. Embedding $C^\ast(\Gamma)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(H_u)$ where $H_u$ is the Hilbert space of the universal representation $(\pi_u, H_u)$ of $C^\ast(\Gamma)$, we can regard $w_\varphi$ as a state on $\mathcal{B}(H_u)$.
We define a map
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\phi: C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)\otimes 1 \cong C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma) &\to C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)\otimes C^\ast(\Gamma) \subseteq C_\lambda^\ast(\Gamma)\otimes \mathcal{B}(H_u)\\
\sum_{t\in\Gamma}\alpha_t\lambda(t)\otimes 1 &\mapsto \sum_{t\in\Gamma}\alpha_t(\lambda(t)\otimes t)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
which is a $\ast$-homomorphism: By Fell's absorption there is a unitary operator $U$ such that $U^\ast(\lambda \otimes \pi_u)(x)U = (\lambda\otimes 1)(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ with
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\|\phi(\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t (\lambda(t)\otimes 1))\| &= \|\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t (\lambda(t)\otimes t)\| = \|(\lambda\otimes \pi_u)(\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t t)\|\\
 &=\|U^\ast (\lambda\otimes1)(\sum_{t\in\Gamma} \alpha_t t)U\| = \|\sum_{t\in\Gamma} \alpha_t(\lambda(t)\otimes 1)\|.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

---

We conclude that $\phi$ extends to a normal $\ast$-homomorphism $\phi:L(\Gamma) \to L(\Gamma)\overline{\otimes} B(H_u)$**(Why?)**.\
Checking that $(id_{L[\Gamma)} \otimes w_\varphi)\circ \phi$ coincides with $m_\varphi$ (identifying $L(\Gamma)\overline{\otimes} 1 \cong L(\Gamma)$) concludes the group von Neumann algebra case. The reduced group $C^\ast$-algebra case follows directly.**(Why?)**

I would be very thankful if someone could give me a hint or some explanations. Thank you very much in advance!

---

[BO08] Brown and Ozawa, "C∗-Algebras and Fnite-Dimensional Approximations"

Comment: In the comment below the answer, I asked a question Maybe you can help as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says in [BO08] that "Fell's principle is spatially implemented". That is, 
$$
\phi:\sum_t\alpha_t\lambda_t\longmapsto \sum_t\alpha_t(\lambda_t\otimes1)=U^*\left(\sum_t\alpha_t(\lambda_t\otimes \pi_u)\right)\,U\longmapsto \sum_t\alpha_t(\lambda_t\otimes \pi_u).
$$
As mentioned in the book, both maps in the composition above are spatial, so they are sot continuous; so in particular $\phi$ is normal.

The argument given in book works for the reduced C$^*$-algebra case if you just don't extend to $L(\Gamma)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again after such a long time. But could you shortly explain how it follows that this map is SOT-continous? I'm still confused by that. To my understanding today, it directly follows that it is normal, since for a bounded, upward directed set of self-adjoint operators $a_i$, the operators $Ua_iU^{\ast} $ also form a upward directed set of selfadjoint operators that is bounded by $UaU ^{\ast} $ where $a$ denotes the upper bound of the original set of operators, $vand $U$ is a unitary.

Comment: Well, that's basically it. If $a_j\to a$ sot, then $Ua_jU^*\to UaU^*$ sot. Is that not clear to you? I can try to explain more if needed.

Comment: I am stressing myself out right now and even less is clear to me than it usually. I thought what you wrote was clear to me but when I tried to check it by calculation I just didn't know where I was going with it. So an elaboration would be helpful. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. If $a_j\to a$ sot, then $$\|Ua_jU^*x-U^*aUx\|=\|U(a_j-a)(U^*x)\|=\|(a_j-a)(U^*x)\|\to0.$$ So $Ua_jU^*\to UaU^*$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Ok, well, that was really stupid of me. For whatever reason my panicked self was trying to check that $Ua_jU^\ast$ strongly converges to $a$. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No worries :) $ $

Comment: @MartinArgerami Do you know why the map $\phi: C_\lambda^*(\Gamma) \to C_\lambda^*(\Gamma) \otimes C^*(\Gamma)$ is well-defined? I believe that one has to show that the map $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\to C_\lambda^*(\Gamma) \otimes C^*(\Gamma): \sum_t \alpha_t \lambda_t \mapsto \sum_t \alpha_t(\lambda_t \otimes t)$ is bounded so that it can extend uniquely to the completion but I don't see why this holds. Is it really a tedious calculation (involving the spatial norm on the tensor product of the C*-algebras) or is something clever going on? Any help/hints will be appreciated :)

Comment: @MartinArgerami It is perfectly ok to say you don't have time, then I'll ask a question :)

Comment: It's already stated above in the question: $$ \|\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t (\lambda(t)\otimes t)\| = \|(\lambda\otimes \pi_u)(\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t t)\|\leq \|\sum_{t\in \Gamma} \alpha_t \|.$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinArgerami This does not quite make sense though does it? $\lambda \otimes \pi_u$ does not take an element of $\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ as input so I guess that's a typo?

Comment: Here Fell's absorption principle was used. Do you think this is correct? @MartinArgerami

Comment: Yes. Why not? $ $

Comment: I'm often unsure about what I'm doing. Thanks for the confirmation though @MartinArgerami

Comment: Oh, that I understand. I'm unsure very often :D